# idiomatic way to do regular expression searches in rails models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, activemodel

in my rails controller, i would like to do a regular expression search of my model. my googling seemed to indicate that i would have to write something like:

```
Model.find( :all, :condition => ["field REGEXP '?' " , regex_str] )
```

which is rather nasty as it implies MySQL syntax (i'm using Postgres).

is there a cleaner way of forcing rails (4 in my case) to do a regexp search on a field?

i also much prefer using using `where()` as it allows me to map my strong parameters (hash) directly to a query. so what i would like is something like:

```
Model.where( params, :match_by => { 'field': '~' } )
```

which would loosely translate to something like (if params['field'] = 'regex_str')

```
select * from models where field ~ regex_str
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no idiomatic way to do this.  There's no built-in support for regular expressions in ActiveRecord.  It'd be impossible to do efficiently unless each database adapter had a database-specific implementation, and not all databases support regular expression matches.  Those that do don't all support the same syntax (for example, Postgres doesn't have the same regexp syntax as Ruby's `Regexp` class).

You'll have to roll your own using SQL, as you've noted in your question.  There are alternatives, however.

For a Postgres-specific solution, check out [pg_search](http://pivotallabs.com/pg-search-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-postgresql-full-text-search/), which uses Postgres's full text search capabilities.  This is very fast and supports fuzzy searching and some pattern matching.

[elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) requires more setup, but is incredibly fast, with some nice gems to make your life easier.  Here's a [RailsCasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/306-elasticsearch-part-1) episode introducing it.  It requires running a separate server, but it's not too hard to get started, and it's powerful.  Still no regular expressions, but it's worth looking at.

If you're just doing a one-off regexp search against a single field, SQL is probably the way to go.